# Problemas con el carousel de materialize

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Hola que tal tengo un problema con el carousel de materialize ,
el caso es el siguiente tengo un carousel que debajo esta el navbar, el carousel solo muestra la mitad o solo una parte de la imagen tal como se puede observar en la imagen adjunta y en celulares se ve que el carousel y el navbar se ven exageradamente separados , dato curioso cuando redimenciono el navegador de chrome recién el carousel funciona como debe de ser .ya eh tratado muchas formas de solucionarlo pero nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es como se deberia de ver 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: asi es como se ve en celulares].

.
dato añadido me aparece esto en la consola 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es mi codigo ( para ver el problema hay que pulsar en el botón de "Página completa")

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    
</head>

<body>
   
        
                <div class="carousel carousel-slider">
                    <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/bWYWhCp/slider1.png"></a>
                    <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DRp84NJ/slider2.png"></a>
                    <a class="carousel-item"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/GT9pGCr/slider3.png"></a>
                </div>
         




        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
                <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
                    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
                    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>

<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
        var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, {
            fullWidth: true
        });
    });

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
        var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
    });
</script>
```